# How to completely remove all traces of a file on Linux? (Overriding everything if needed)

Tags: linux, hardware, file-system, deletion

How can I delete a file and completely remove it from the system FOREVER. I does have in mind that it's needed to override it. But how can I do that?

Comment: The content, or the whole file with all metadata? What type of storage?

Comment: "Overriding everything if needed" in your title suggests you are prepared to accept collateral damage. If that is the case, smashing through the disk or ssd with a stone chisel, and smashing up the remaining junk with a fair sized hammer would do the job.

Comment: the whole file and it can be a HD/SSD.

Comment: smashing can do it. but i think that what i mean is more like scrub and bleachbit. thanks  ;D

Comment: Just offering options. The 'good enough' solution depends, as always, on your threat model.

Comment: yeap. you're right!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Install scrub (secure erasing tool) and bleachbit (slack space scrubber)

Comment: I wonder whether both these software are designed for magnetic media; and whether they help with SSDs too.